# Stable and unstable set of a dynamical system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Consider the following system of differential equations.
$$ \dot{x} = Ax $$ with $$A=\left[ \begin{matrix}2&3\\-3&2\end{matrix} \right] $$
and with initial value $x(0)=x_0$.

I want to calculate the stable set of the origin. This is the union of all orbits of the solutions that converge to the origin for $t \to \infty$. Similarly, the unstable set is defined as the union of all orbits that converge to the origin for $t \to -\infty$.

I think I found a solution by calculating the solution of the differential equation. The stable set is $\{ 0 \}$ and the unstable set is $\mathbb{R}^2$. But it seems to me that there must be a much more efficient way to tackle this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a standard problem in linear dynamical systems. And the easiest way to find stable sets is to find the eigenvalues. According to that, one can categorize whether the origin is a source, sink, saddle etc. The classic reference on this is Hirsch and Smale's [Differential equations, dynamical systems and linear algebra](http://books.google.co.in/books/about/Differential_Equations_Dynamical_Systems.html?id=UG4Rh4OG-hUC&redir_esc=y). The book has a second edition which includes some chaos theory but I prefer the original first edition.